# Java Code using Methods?

Tags: java, methods

I have a class assignment where we have to make a dice game but using multiple methods. My issue is that i can't get past one of my methods any idea why?

```
    {

        int d1 = rollDie(1,6);
        int d2 = rollDie(1,6);
        int d3 = rollDie(1,6);
            boolean triple =  isTriple(d1, d2, d3);
            boolean pair = isPair(d1, d2, d3);
            boolean straight = isStraight(d1, d2, d3);
            boolean junker = isNone(d1, d2, d3);
            if (triple == True ){
                System.out.println("You got a Triple!");
                printDice(d1, d2, d3);
                wins = wins + 1;
                }
            else if (pair == True ){
                System.out.println("You got a Pair!");
                printDice(d1, d2, d3);
                ties = ties + 1;
                }
            else if (straight == True ){
                System.out.println("You got a Straight!");
                printDice(d1, d2, d3);
                wins = wins + 1;
                }
            else if (junker == True ){
                System.out.println("Try Again!");
                printDice(d1, d2, d3);
                loses = loses + 1;
```

my Screen looks like this
As shown i only get triple but I am also supposed to get pair, straight and junker.:

```
welcome to eDice
-----------------
Rules
First you will roll your dice. 
Then you'll get a result. 

Triple and straigth = win. 
Pair = tie. 
Anything else = loses.
Let's Play y/n: y
You got a Triple!
Dice 1 = 2  Dice 2 = 5  Dice 3 = 6
Let's Play y/n: y
You got a Triple!
Dice 1 = 5  Dice 2 = 1  Dice 3 = 6
Let's Play y/n: y
You got a Triple!
Dice 1 = 6  Dice 2 = 2  Dice 3 = 6
Let's Play y/n: y
You got a Triple!
Dice 1 = 6  Dice 2 = 3  Dice 3 = 1
Let's Play y/n: y
You got a Triple!
Dice 1 = 3  Dice 2 = 2  Dice 3 = 4
Let's Play y/n: n
Why not you scared?
Do you want to play again y/n: n
Goodbye!
Wins 5
Ties 0
Loses: 0
```

Here is my rollDie method:

```
public static int rollDie(int min, int max){
    int dice = (int)(Math.random() * 6) + 1;    
    return dice;
```

My Triple, Pair, Straight, and None methods:

```
public static boolean isTriple(int d1, int d2, int d3){

    if (d1 == d2 && d2 == d3){
    }
    return True;}   
public static boolean isStraight(int d1, int d2, int d3){
    if (d2 == d1 + 1 && d3 == d2 + 1 || d1 == d2 + 1 && d2 == d3 + 1){
    }
    return True;}
public static boolean isPair(int d1, int d2, int d3){
    if (d1 == d2 || d2 == d3 || d1 == d3){
}
    return True;}
public static boolean isNone(int d1, int d2, int d3){
    if (!(isTriple(d1, d2, d3)|| isStraight(d1, d2, d3)|| isPair(d1, d2, d3))){
}
    return True;}
```

Comment: Please provide full code?

Comment: kindly show your rollDie method

Comment: share isTriple,isPair.. method code also..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your methods you check conditions but you dont return false never, so first check (isTriple) is always true, change in this way:

```
public static boolean isTriple(int d1, int d2, int d3){
    if (d1 == d2 && d2 == d3){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}   

public static boolean isStraight(int d1, int d2, int d3){
    if (d2 == d1 + 1 && d3 == d2 + 1 || d1 == d2 + 1 && d2 == d3 + 1){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public static boolean isPair(int d1, int d2, int d3){
    if (d1 == d2 || d2 == d3 || d1 == d3){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public static boolean isNone(int d1, int d2, int d3){
    if (!(isTriple(d1, d2, d3)|| isStraight(d1, d2, d3)|| isPair(d1, d2, d3))){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

NOTES:

- Use `true` and `false` instead `True` or `False`.
- change main part accordingly
- make the checks inside if statement
- check from less improbable first

```
int d1 = rollDie(1,6);
int d2 = rollDie(1,6);
int d3 = rollDie(1,6);

if (isStraight(d1, d2, d3)){
    System.out.println("You got a Straight!");
    printDice(d1, d2, d3);
    wins = wins + 1;
}
else if (isTriple(d1, d2, d3)){
    System.out.println("You got a Triple!");
    printDice(d1, d2, d3);
    wins = wins + 1;
}
else if (isPair(d1, d2, d3)){
    System.out.println("You got a Pair!");
    printDice(d1, d2, d3);
    ties = ties + 1;
}
else if (isNone(d1, d2, d3)){
    System.out.println("Try Again!");
    printDice(d1, d2, d3);
    loses = loses + 1; 
}
```

## CLARIFICATIONS

> thanks it works now but can you explain why?

Sure, let's see.

You had this method:

```
public static boolean isTriple(int d1, int d2, int d3){
    if (d1 == d2 && d2 == d3){
    }
    return True;
}
```

**What happened here?** you make the correct check in the `if (d1 == d2 && d2 == d3)` and if dices make a tripple, condition will be `true` and code will go through if body (lines between `{` and `}`), but **nothing happened because the body of the `if` statement was empty**, check it here:

```
public static boolean isTriple(int d1, int d2, int d3){
    if (d1 == d2 && d2 == d3) { // starts body
        // OOOOPS!!! EMPTY BODY 
    } // ends body
    return True; // this line is ALWAYS EXECUTED
}
```

**How do i solved it?**, just adding 2 flows to your method, one if the if condition was true and another otherwise.

```
public static boolean isTriple(int d1, int d2, int d3){
    if (d1 == d2 && d2 == d3){  
        return true;   // if condition is true return true
    }
    return false;
}
```

**Remember if your code flow finds a `return` statement the rest of the code in the method will be ignored!!!**

This method I think can be more clear to you if I show you the equivalent:

```
public static boolean isTriple(int d1, int d2, int d3){
    if (d1 == d2 && d2 == d3){  
        return true;   // if condition is true return true
    } else {
        return false;  // if condition is false return false
    }
}
```

This is question of style, one of my teachers was totally against more than one return statement in each method so he used to do:

```
public static boolean isTriple(int d1, int d2, int d3){
    boolean isTriple = false;
    if (d1 == d2 && d2 == d3){  
        isTriple = true;
    }
    return isTriple;
}
```

Or you can use a oneliner, not always recommended but much more beautiful in this case:

```
public static boolean isTriple(int d1, int d2, int d3){
    return d1 == d2 && d2 == d3;
}
```

Comment: It still produces the same results but thanks i forgot to add that.

Comment: have you checked my last update? I made a mistake in the return statements of the methods, kindly check it now

Comment: is it working ok now? there is some part you want me to clarify? @Umbra97 don't hesitate to ask, not all SO users are so rude ;)

Comment: thanks that clears it up a lot! I didn't know i had an empty body.

Answer (score 0):

Anyway it seems that your `isTriple` function that we can't see always returns `true` whatever values you give it.

Then you loop through it, i assume. And it will always stop at triple
You said you need to use different functions and i understand but its kinda weird in this situation but oke.

This is a bit better code in my opinion. You don't reuse those statements called pair and go on more then ones so its kinda useless to put them into a variable in this case. Also you checked if its true but If statements already do that for you.

```
int d1 = rollDie(1,6);
int d2 = rollDie(1,6);
int d3 = rollDie(1,6);

if (isTriple(d1, d2, d3)){
    System.out.println("You got a Triple!");
    printDice(d1, d2, d3);
    wins = wins + 1;
    }
else if (isPair(d1, d2, d3)){
    System.out.println("You got a Pair!");
    printDice(d1, d2, d3);
    ties = ties + 1;
    }
else if (isStraight(d1, d2, d3)){
    System.out.println("You got a Straight!");
    printDice(d1, d2, d3);
    wins = wins + 1;
    }
else if (isNone(d1, d2, d3)){
    System.out.println("Try Again!");
    printDice(d1, d2, d3);
    loses = loses + 1;
```

(Got to low of a score to post a comment so i did this)

Comment: Thanks Jordi. I didn't know you could highlight words like that.